# Why did Ryan say that he was right about the Febergé egg?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-night

In *Game Night (2018)*, at Donald Anderton's place, Ryan and Sarah encounter a man opening a locker in which they saw the Febergé egg.

> Ryan: Holy shit. I'm right again.

Ryan never told anyone that the Febergé egg could be found in the locker at 
Donald Anderton's place. Actually, Ryan doesn't know anymore about the Febergé 
egg than Brooks does.

Why did Ryan say that he was right about the Febergé egg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he was referring to the fight-club stuff that was happening in the rich man's house as he has mentioned it before in the movie. If I am not mistaken he says this while walking down the stairs and starts noticing what is happening in the basement?

Answer (score 2):

When everyone splits up to find the egg, but Ryan stays in the fight club room, Sarah asks Ryan what he's doing, to which he responds:

> Well, who says the egg isn't in here.

When they both later notice the egg in the safe, Ryan says he's "right again" because the egg was, in fact, in the room he chose.

(He says "again" because he was also right a little while before that about the fight club being a real thing.)